# The table returns column number instead of count

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using this query but it returns column numbers instead of the count `count(bedroom_count)`:

```sql
select
  states,
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  10
from
  (
    select
      states,
      bedroom_count
    from
      hive_metastore.property_db_dev.datatree_assessor_silver
  ) PIVOT (
    count(bedroom_count) FOR bedroom_count IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
  )
ORDER BY
  states;
```

Comment: MySQL does not support PIVOT. Check your DBMS carefully (MS SQL == SQL Server ?)

Comment: sorry @Akina its not mysql. Please have a look at this link. https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/pivot-in-sql.html

Comment: Your last comment isn't helpful since the link does not specify which sql dialect is being used.. and as stated in the first comment PIVOT is not supported by mysql..

Comment: @P.Salmon I am using spark SQL on databricks

Comment: @AnkitKhanna edit your question. Change the tag from "mysql" to "apache-spark-sql" or "databricks-sql" (the rigth choice only you can know), so it will be better found from members with the knowlege of the sql engine used by you.

Comment: @h.m.i.13 its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use back-ticks to escape the column names otherwise Spark is interpreting them as integer literals in your query:

```sql
SELECT states, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`
FROM (
   SELECT states,
          bedroom_count
   FROM   hive_metastore.property_db_dev.datatree_assessor_silver 
) 
PIVOT (
   count(bedroom_count) FOR bedroom_count IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
)
ORDER BY states;
```

Or simply use `select *` if you want all the pivoted columns:

```
SELECT *
-- ...
ORDER BY states;
```